# Magento Order Creation Programatically only working on one shipping method

Tags: php, api, magento

I am using the code below as part of a script to create Magento Orders programatically. The script works fine when I use

> freeshipping_freeshipping

as the shipping method. However, when I choose any other shipping method such as a custom shipping method,flatrate_flatrate or usps_1 e.t.c, it gives me the error:

> "Please Specify a shipping method"

I have searched everywhere but was unable to find a solution. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks.

```
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
    ->setShippingMethod($shipping_method);
```

Edit:

I got it to work with flatrate for non US orders and an extension freeadminshipping on both US and non US orders. However, still unable to use any of the UPS or USPS shipping methods.

Answer (score 0):

This method create Order and I have use this in my project it working. In your code please remove shipping method set code and try I hope that work fine for you. otherwise you can use below my code.

```
public function createOrderAction($paymentMethod) {
    try {
    $checkout_session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $cq = $checkout_session->getQuote();
    $cq->assignCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());
    $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($checkout_session->getQuoteId()); // Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
    //Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()

    $items = $quoteObj->getAllItems();                  

    $quoteObj->reserveOrderId();

      // set payment method 

    $quotePaymentObj = $quoteObj->getPayment(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment
    $quotePaymentObj->setMethod($paymentMethod);

    $quoteObj->setPayment($quotePaymentObj);


    // convert quote to order
    $convertQuoteObj = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote');

    $quoteObj->setShippingAddress($cq->getShippingAddress());
    $quoteObj->setBillingAddress($cq->getBillingAddress());
    $orderObj = $convertQuoteObj->addressToOrder($quoteObj->getShippingAddress());

    $orderPaymentObj = $convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quotePaymentObj);


    // convert quote addresses
    $orderObj->setBillingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getBillingAddress()));

    $orderObj->setShippingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getShippingAddress()));

    // set payment options
    $orderObj->setPayment($convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quoteObj->getPayment()));

    // convert quote items
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
        $orderItem = $convertQuoteObj->itemToOrderItem($item);
        $orderItem->setWholesaler($item->getWholesaler());
        $orderItem->setComment($item->getComment());
        $options = array();
        if ($productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct())) {
            $options = $productOptions;
        }
        if ($addOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
            $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($addOptions->getValue());
        }
        if ($options) {
            $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
        }
        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            $orderItem->setParentItem($orderObj->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId()));
        }
        $orderObj->addItem($orderItem);
    }
        $orderObj->setCanShipPartiallyItem(false);
        $orderObj->place();
        $quoteObj->setIsActive(0)->save();
        $orderObj->save(); 
        $orderObj->sendNewOrderEmail(); 
        return $orderObj->getId();
    } catch (Exception $e){     
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        Mage::log($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sunny, thanks for your answer. 

I am using the order creation in an API file which will receive the product items, payment data and shipping method to create the order. I am not using the checkout session, instead using `sales/service_quote`  to create the order. I am unable to find where the shipping method is being set in your code as I need to charge the customer for that as well.